# How to ignore eror message "dbnull to string is not valid" and dont load empty cells to my vb form

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010, oledbconnection, oledbcommand, dbnull

When I click search button error occurs conversion *dbnull to type string is not valid*.

I think there's no data in some cells in my database.

its not a problem to have empty cells and if there are empty cells I don't want to load them to my form.

Here's what I tried *ButtonClickEvent* :

```
     Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        
        con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Dimuth De Zoysa\Documents\divimaga_DB.accdb")
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM MainE WHERE Job ='" + ComboBox1.Text + "'  ", con)

        con.Open()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While dr.Read
            jobid = dr("JobID")
            TextBox1.Text = dr("PROCEDURE")
            TextBox2.Text = dr("ReleventDocuments")
            TextBox3.Text = dr("ImportantPoints")
            TextBox4.Text = dr("officer")
        End While

        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have wouldn't compile with `Option Strict On` even if there were no nulls in the data. That means it's bad code because `Option Strict` should pretty much always be `On`.  The `Text` property of a `TextBox` is type `String`, while you're assigning `Object` references to those properties.  You should be casting or converting to type `String` already.  If you call `ToString` on each field value then you kill two birds with one stone because null fields will contain `DBNull.Value` and calling `ToString` on that returns an empty `String`.

```
TextBox1.Text = dr("PROCEDURE").ToString()
TextBox2.Text = dr("ReleventDocuments").ToString()
TextBox3.Text = dr("ImportantPoints").ToString()
TextBox4.Text = dr("officer").ToString()
```

Comment: This will save me a headache.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, wrap your column value to `CStr("" & dr("column"))`:

```
While dr.Read
    jobid = CStr("" & dr("JobID"))
    TextBox1.Text = CStr("" & dr("PROCEDURE"))
    TextBox2.Text = CStr("" & dr("ReleventDocuments"))
    TextBox3.Text = CStr("" & dr("ImportantPoints"))
    TextBox4.Text = CStr("" & dr("officer"))
End While
```

Another solution, using [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring):

```
While dr.Read
    jobid = dr("JobID").ToString()
    TextBox1.Text = dr("PROCEDURE").ToString()
    TextBox2.Text = dr("ReleventDocuments").ToString()
    TextBox3.Text = dr("ImportantPoints").ToString()
    TextBox4.Text = dr("officer").ToString()
End While
```